# How to find string after any tag in the match

Tags: php, regex, perl

My string is

```
grunds&\#x00E4;tzlich Prek&\#x00E4;re&\#x201C;.<a id="cein_fn31"
href="einleitung.html#ein_fn31"><sup>31</sup></a> Nur in den
mannigfaltigen Spielarten des Festlichen ist
```

I need a regex pattern to match all the contents after the tag closing (i.e :

```
Nur in den mannigfaltigen Spielarten des Festlichen ist
```

**note:** tag name may vary anything

Anybody please share any ideas

Comment: How you define a "tag"?

Comment: `print $string =~ /([^<>]+)$/`

Answer (score 1):

This program works by finding all characters that are not angle brackets `<>` at the end of the string.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = <<'__END_STRING__';
grunds&\#x00E4;tzlich Prek&\#x00E4;re&\#x201C;.<a id="cein_fn31"
href="einleitung.html#ein_fn31"><sup>31</sup></a> Nur in den
mannigfaltigen Spielarten des Festlichen ist
__END_STRING__

my ($subtext) = $s =~ /([^<>]*)\z/;

print $subtext;
```

**output**

```
 Nur in den
mannigfaltigen Spielarten des Festlichen ist
```

Comment: Thanks Borodin for Revision and answer, Ill check and reply to you back

Comment: Thanks Borodin it works so well, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

#### An alternate regex free solution

The code uses `strrpos()` as a lookbehind to find the closing `>` and chops off up to that using `substr()`

```
echo $str = trim(strip_tags(substr($str,strrpos($str,'>')+1)));
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/146985)</kbd>

Comment: Nice solution, but wouldn't this only work with `<a>` tags? The OP states in the question that "*note: tag name may vary anything*".

Comment: @AmalMurali, Modified it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Below code also.

```
<?php
$string = "<a>Hii</a>
           <div>div tag here</div>
           <p>para tag here</p>";
$string = str_replace(">","&#*#&", $string);
$string_arr = explode("&#*#&", $string);

$final_arr = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($string_arr); $i++){
    $string_arr[$i] = trim(strip_tags($string_arr[$i]));
    if($string_arr[$i] != ''){
        $final_arr[] = $string_arr[$i];
    }
}
print_r($final_arr);
?>
```